# What is the best way fill in database core data at first launch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How add to database initial values?
Maybe  is there are place for it in code? Action that do one time after application install?

Comment: while you are adding values to database then check if value that is going to db is nil or [NSNULL null] then place a default value at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that : http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated
or this tutorial :
http://hackazach.net/code/2013/03/26/ios-core-data-prepopulation

In a nutshell, either you can at first launch (define by a BOOL in NSUSerDefault for exemple) parse a file (JSON, XML, etc..) and insert the content in database, or prefill the sqllite database with a mac app or iOS app on your mac, put the database pre-filled in your bundle and move it at the right place at first launch.